# Check if string is present in String Literal Union Type Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have this String literal union type:

```
enum A { Foo = 'foo' }
enum B { Bar = 'bar' }
type FooBars = A | B
type Bazes = `${FooBars}`;

const isBazes = (msg: string): msg is Bazes => {
  return //
};
```

Given `isBazes('foo') // true` or `isBazes('bar') //true` or `isBazes('baz') //false`

How would I perform the check to see if a string is present in the `Bazez` string literal union type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, if you wanted to ascertain the string is one of the  enum values, you may do this:

```
enum A { Foo = 'foo' }
enum B { Bar = 'bar' }
type FooBars = A | B
type Bazes = `${FooBars}`;

const isBazes = (msg: string): msg is Bazes => {
  return Object.values<string>(A).includes(msg) || Object.values<string>(B).includes(msg)
};

console.log(isBazes(A.Foo)); // true
console.log(isBazes(B.Bar)); // true
console.log(isBazes('baz')); // false
console.log(isBazes('foo')); // true
console.log(isBazes('bar')); // true
```

Here is the playground link: https://tsplay.dev/wjJKlw

I have a feeling I got the question wrong, please let me know if that's the case. :)

Comment: Is there now way of utilising the `Bazez` type? ie. not having to reference every single Enum?

Comment: Type gets erased at runtime. So, I doubt there's a way to utilize that in implementatioin.